# Why does using QWORD in MSVC give an "invalid operand type" error?

Tags: c, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

I am learning elementary in-line assembly for self-intrest, and was playing around with defining some load-in-memory instructions. After figuring out how to transfer a byte (defined as a char) array to a differently sized variable using the line `mov [size] ptr [Memory]`, I did some test runs. `byte ptr`, `word ptr`, and `dword ptr` worked great. However, the assembly code to load a qword, or `QWORD ptr` always gives me a an error that says `"invalid operand type"`. Why is this?

Here are my macro definitions:

```c
//x86, MSVC, Visual Studio.
typedef signed char byte;
#pragma region Instructions
// ldb - load byte
#define ldb(reg, mem) __asm { \
    __asm mov al, byte ptr mem \
    __asm mov reg, al \
}
// ldw - load word
#define ldw(reg, mem) __asm { \
    __asm mov ax, WORD PTR mem \
    __asm mov reg, ax \
}
// ldq - load double
#define ldq(reg, mem) __asm { \
    __asm mov eax, DWORD PTR mem \
    __asm mov reg, eax \
}
// ldo - load quad
#define ldo(reg, mem) __asm { \
    __asm mov rax, QWORD PTR mem \
    __asm mov reg, rax \
}
#pragma endregion
```

And here is my testing code:

```c
int main() {
    byte test_memory[1000] = { 0 }; // don't worry about other 999 indexes.
    test_memory[0] = 0x12;;

    byte reg = 0;
    // load byte
    ldb(reg, test_memory[0]);
    printf("ldb: %x\n", reg); // prints 0x12
    // load word
    word reg2 = 0;
    ldw(reg2, test_memory[0]);
    printf("ldw: %x\n", reg); // prints 0x12
    // load double
    dword reg3 = 0;
    ldq(reg3, test_memory[0]); // prints 0x12
    printf("ldq: %x\n", reg);
    // load quad
    qword reg4 = 0;
    ldo(reg4, test_memory[0]); // error!!!
    printf("ldo: %x\n", reg);
    return 0;
}
```

If there is something I am missing here, any help would be much appriceated.

Comment: Are you sure you're building for 64bit?  Because I thought MSVC didn't support inline asm for 64bit.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Oops, turns out it was set to just x86. It's fixed now. 

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I now have a theroy that x86 (32bit?) doesn't support `qword`?

Comment: Well, it's surely not going to let you access a 64bit register (rax).

Comment: Ahh, that must be it. Thank you.

Comment: Correct.  Unlike with 386 and 32-bit regs in 16-bit mode, there weren't any spare opcodes for AMD64 to add new prefixes for 32-bit machine code to access 64-it registers.  And yes, in MSVC, "x86" specifically means 32-bit mode x86.

Comment: Also, why is `ldq` a 32-bit load?  Quad-byte?  Very confusing to anyone familiar with assembly for mainstream ISAs like x86, where D and Q mean double and quad *word*.  Especially when you have an `ldw` macro that does take its size in words; for consistency you'd call that `ldd`, which would be extra confusing to even more people because many non-x86 ISAs have an `ldrd` or `ld` or equivalent instruction that loads with double-word width (into a 64-bit register, or into two registers depending on the ISA.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said the comments, I was trying to access `rax` in a 32-bit environment. Oops!